# Count how often an int from an array appears in another array in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, count, numbers

I'm trying to solve an exercise that wants me to first create 2 arrays, sort them in ascending order and then count how many times a number from the first array appears in the second array. I'm almost finished. Everything seems to work perfectly fine except for one line that ruins the whole code. And I can't figure out why. I'm very new to C this is my very first exercise in this language.

Here's the code. I have commented the line that is not working:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int a[]) {
    int i, j, l, t; 
    l = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < l + 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < (l - i); j++) {
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                t = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = t;
            }
        }
    }
}

void numberOfTimes(int a[], int b[]) {
    int al = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    int bl = sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]);
    int i, p, c = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= al; i++) {
        for (p = 0; i <= bl; p++) {
            if (a[i] == b[p]) {
                c++;       // <-------- This line doesn't work. Why?
            }
        }   
        printf("(%d, %d) ", a[i], c);
    }
}

void main() {
    int maxarraylen = 1000, i;
    int a[maxarraylen];
    int b[maxarraylen];
    int v, t;

    printf("Type elements of A seperated by spaces. Do not enter duplicates (type 'end' to stop): ");
    while (scanf("%d", &a[i]) == 1)
        i++;
    scanf("%*s");
    i = 0;

    printf("Type elements of B seperated by spaces(type 'end' to stop): ");
    while (scanf("%d", &b[i]) == 1)
        i++;
    scanf("%*s");

    sort(a);
    sort(b);

    numberOfTimes(a, b);
}
```

The idea is that the code will first sort both arrays and then print it out in the format `(n, m)`. `n` is an `int` from array `a` and `m` is how many times it appears in array `b`.

For example you enter this:

```
a = {3, 2 ,1}
b = {1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1}
```

And the code does first sort:

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3}
```

And then prints out how many times a number from an array `a` appears in `b`:

```
(1, 2) (2, 2) (3, 3)
```

Comment: `int a[], int b[]` : `a` and `b` are pointer, not array. So `int al = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);` is `int al = sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks for the help but it didn't change much. There is still a problem with the line I've marked. The program crashes without any information after entering the array numbers. If I write break; instead of c++; the code works. The output is (1, 0) (2, 0) (3, 0). I just can't make it count.

Comment: He means `int al` has a fixed value regardless how large the array you pass to the function. Usually `sizeof(int*)` is 8 or 4 and `sizeof(int)` is 4

Comment: The values of `al` and `bl` are not correct.

Comment: @e0k Does that mean the program crashes because it tries to compare a position in the array which doesn't exist? How can I fix this? I'm a little overwhelmed right now. It's literally my first code in C and they expect me to be able to make the code work basically without knowing how C works.

Comment: First,You need to pass the number counted at the time of the input element to each of the function.

Comment: Second, `i <= al` occures out of bound. also `i < bl` --> `p < bl`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compute the array size from a pointer received as an argument: `l = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);` only works if `a` is an array, not a pointer.

You must pass the array sizes to functions `sort` and `numberOfTimes`. In your code, the array size is not what you need, but the number of elements actually parsed for each array.  You must store these numbers specifically.

Note that your sorting code is incorrect, you should not adjust `j`'s upper bound to avoid accessing array elements beyond the end.  The same is true for the `numberOfTimes` function.  The count `c` must be set to `0` for each new element of `a` that you search in `b`.

Note that your code does not take advantage of the fact that `a` and `b` are sorted.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int a[], int l) {
    int i, j, t; 

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < l - i - 1; j++) {
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                t = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = t;
            }
        }
    }
}

void numberOfTimes(int a[], int al, int b[], int bl) {
    int i, p, c;

    for (i = 0; i < al; i++) {
        c = 0;
        for (p = 0; p < bl; p++) {
            if (a[i] == b[p]) {
                c++;       // <-------- This line doesn't work. Why?
            }
        }   
        printf("(%d, %d) ", a[i], c);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int maxarraylen = 1000, i;
    int a[maxarraylen];
    int b[maxarraylen];
    int al, bl, v, t;

    printf("Type elements of A separated by spaces. Do not enter duplicates (type 'end' to stop): ");
    for (i = 0; i < maxarraylen; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) != 1)
            break;
    }
    scanf("%*s");
    al = i;

    printf("Type elements of B separated by spaces(type 'end' to stop): ");
    for (i = 0; i < maxarraylen; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &b[i]) != 1)
            break;
    }
    scanf("%*s");
    bl = i;

    sort(a, al);
    sort(b, bl);

    numberOfTimes(a, al, b, bl);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll keep that in mind. I just found out why the code didn't work and I'm very ashamed to write that here. The code still works even if the array size from a pointer is received as an argument. It didn't work because I've accidently wrote an i instead of a p in the second for loop in the numberOfTimes function.

Comment: @oschi: yes, that's another bug, but all other ones need fixing too. Please click on the grey check mark below the answer score to accept it.